# Flutter a different version of package installed of the one on pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

so I have a problem where I used a flutter package in one of my project which is flutter_downloader v1.10.2, but when I run pub get, the one got installed at my src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org is flutter_downloader v1.10.4.

I've tried everything, flutter clean, pub get, delete the package from my pubspec, still the same. I've even tried using flutter_downloader v1.10.2 on another project, and used pub get, v1.10.2 is the one got installed in the said directory. Now I got 2 different flutter_downloader version, even though I only used v1.10.2 on all my project. Only that one project that had this problem.

Anyone got the answer for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the fluttertoast package and I solved it by removing '^' from the version name in the pubspec.yaml file.

BEFORE:

```
dependencies:
  fluttertoast: ^8.1.2
```

SOLUTION:

```
dependencies:
  fluttertoast: 8.1.2
```